# "commandLine" in build.gradle causes Android Studio 0.2.10 build to fail

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

In build.gradle, I have `commandLine 'jni/ndk-build.cmd'` inside one of my tasks.

The contents of ndk-build.cmd is very simple:

`[path containing ndk]\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd APP_ABI="all" NDK_DEBUG=0`

This works fine if I run "gradle assemble" in the command prompt.  Android Studio however fails in the build process:

```
Information: 1 error
Information: 0 warnings
Error: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':mytask'
       > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'jni/ndk-build.cmd''
```

Is `commandLine` not supported in Android Studio?  If it matters, I've also tried running Android Studio as administrator (Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

If Making in Android Studio on Windows, the command in build.gradle must be `commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'jni\\be-arm7.cmd'`

The `'cmd'` argument isn't necessary if the script is being run from the command prompt, which is why I saw no error doing so.